# Exception: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()

Tags: android, button, sdk, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make "Share" button in Action Bar of Android Application.
Here my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

and fragment part:

```
{
private String mForecastText;

public PlaceholderFragment() {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private Intent sharedIntentMaker(){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastText + "#SunshineApp");
    return shareIntent;
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharedIntentMaker());

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    TextView textIntent = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textIntent);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    mForecastText = intent.getStringExtra("INT_PS");
    textIntent.setText(mForecastText);
    return rootView;
}
```

When I run my app on emulator or even real device, I get exception:

```
AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
```

and it links to onCreateOptionsMenu()'s strings:

```
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharedIntentMaker());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S.: Stacktrace of error from logcat:

> 01-11 13:03:17.490    2331-2331/com.*****.*****.***** E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.*****.*****.*****, PID: 2331

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()

        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:645)
        at com.project.malina.sunsine.DetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(DetailActivity.java:70)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1989)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud853/lessons/1474559101/concepts/14808087260923

Check bottom of this page "Diff for this note" section. It specifically says to use "android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First, you cannot use `android.widget.ShareActionProvider` with the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport (e.g., `ActionBarActivity`). Either use the `appcompat-v7` version of `ShareActionProvider`, or move everything over to the native action bar.

Second, if you stick with `appcompat-v7`, then you cannot safely use `getActionProvider()`, as that method will not exist on API Level 10 and below. Replace `menuItem.getActionProvider()` with `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem)`.

FWIW, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/Share) that implements the `appcompat-v7` edition of `ShareActionProvider`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I missed information from official Android Developer site, that use android.widget.ShareActionProvider for API >=14. Thanks!

Comment: The sample project is really helpful. Make sure you check out the menu xml file - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/AppCompat/Share/app/src/main/res/menu/actions.xml - as well as the activity code - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/AppCompat/Share/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/sap/MainActivity.java - because you may run into new problems otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

You can follow the pattern in Code Sample from Google in link below.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider

The easiest way is to go to your Android Studio => File, Import Sample. Then type in "Share Action Provider".

[image]

Below are the code involved in creating Share Action Menu Item with ShareActionProvider with ActionBarCompat, backwards compatible to API v7.

MainActivity.java

```
// BEGIN_INCLUDE(get_sap)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu resource
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    // Retrieve the share menu item
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

    // Now get the ShareActionProvider from the item
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

    // Get the ViewPager's current item position and set its ShareIntent.
    int currentViewPagerItem = ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager)).getCurrentItem();
    setShareIntent(currentViewPagerItem);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
// END_INCLUDE(get_sap

private void setShareIntent(int position) {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(update_sap)
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        // Get the currently selected item, and retrieve it's share intent
        ContentItem item = mItems.get(position);
        Intent shareIntent = item.getShareIntent(MainActivity.this);

        // Now update the ShareActionProvider with the new share intent
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(update_sap)
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!--
  To use ShareActionProvider provided by ActionBarCompat, we reference the class by set the
  support:actionProviderClass attribute with the full class name of ShareActionProvider.
-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:title="@string/menu_share"
    support:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    support:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: This is great help. Keep an eye out in main_menu.xml that for actionProviderClass its also using the support v7 version.

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps:

**Step.1)** To add a "share" action to your activity, put a `ShareActionProvider` in the app bar's menu resource. Like this

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
      android:title="@string/share"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Please note the `actionProviderClass`

**Step.2)** Now you make sure that in your Activity Java Class you import same `ShareActionProvider`

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

**Step.3)**
Below section for `onCreate` methond

```
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);

        ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_share));
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIt());
```

Intent method

```
    private Intent shareIt() {
        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        String shareMsgBody = "Hello, Share this with world !!";

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareAndPromotionBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Spread the message!!"));
        return intent;
    }
```