# Share button not working version issue

Tags: java, android

I want to add share button to my app which shares the play store link of the app. For this I am using ShareActionProvider. But after implementing I am getting many errors. I also tried to change the code as asked in the error panel but still I am getting error. Following is the java code and menu xml file

```
public class KaviAshokActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView1;
    private Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaviashok);

         /* Admob related important code*/
        mAdView1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Kruti_Dev_010.ttf");
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todaypoem);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.marathipoems);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hindipoems);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutauthor);

        b1.setTypeface(tf);b2.setTypeface(tf);b3.setTypeface(tf);b4.setTypeface(tf);

        b1.setTextSize(20);b2.setTextSize(20);b3.setTextSize(20);b4.setTextSize(20);

        //b1.setPadding(10, 15, 15, 0);
        b1.setText("आज की कविता");b2.setText("मराठी");
        b3.setText("हिंदी");b4.setText("परिचय");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent i1,sharingIntent;
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.developers_id) {
            i1 = new Intent(this, DevelopersActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }

        if (id == R.id.menu_item_share) {
            sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            //String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
            String shareBody = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
            shareBody = shareBody + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Orion.Soft \n\n";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClickSelection(View view) {

        Intent i;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.todaypoem:
                i = new Intent(this, TodaysPoemActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.marathipoems:
                i = new Intent(this, MarathiActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.hindipoems:
                i = new Intent(this, HindiActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.aboutauthor:
                i = new Intent(this, AboutAuthorActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the menu xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:kaviashok="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <item
      android:id="@+id/developers_id"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:title="About Developers"
      kaviashok:showAsAction="never"
      />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    kaviashok:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass=
        "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

And these are the errors

```
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process:      in.protechlabz.www.kaviashok, PID: 31772
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime:     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:645)
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at in.protechlabz.www.kaviashok.KaviAshokActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(KaviAshokActivity.java:58)
08-03 17:39:26.410 31772-31772/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2856)
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27887763/2900127)

Comment: Already checked. Problem still persists

Comment: If you may update your code then

Comment: After updating I get Incompatible types, cannot cast 'android.Supportv4.View.ActionProvider to 'android.Widget.ShareActionProvider' error