# Sharing intent in onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, performance

I want to add share intent in android app bar menu

This is my code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_with_drawer, menu);
  item = menu.findItem(R.id.shareintent);
  mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
  playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
               getPackageName();
  yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
  shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
               .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();

  mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  return true;
}
```

[Please click here for see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjjW2.png)

Comment: You should include the error message in your post, not link to an image. It could help future users looking for this exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you how to fix it. Use `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem)`

This is also documented here:

[Exception: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887716/exception-this-is-not-supported-use-menuitemcompat-getactionprovider)

Comment: just an hint for next times, if the problem is already found on SO flag the question as duplicate instead of posting an answer with the link to the old post :)

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: hello can you please help me

Comment: please tell me how to increase text size of Tab layout text.